# Cannot query "Cast object (1)": Must be "Person" instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to create a detail-list of my actor where it will show all the shows he has been a cast member of. This is part of mozilla's challenge yourself section at the end of the [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Generic_views).

I am having trouble filtering my *class Cast* so that I can get a specific Actor.

I do not understand why the filter is not working. If self.object has a value of '3' for example, it should be filtering out all of the actors and only display the actor with the id of 3. But that does not seem to be the case. I also am not understanding the error code it is tossing out. My Cast class does have a foreignkey to person.

Similar to my show details page, instead of casts, I want it to be the actor's starred in movies.

[Image of my Show Details Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6LJp.png)

View

```
class ActorDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Cast
    template_name = 'show/actor-detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ActorDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['casts'] = Cast.objects.filter(person_id=self.object)

        return context
```

Models

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Character(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    on_which_show = models.ForeignKey('Show', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Cast(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cast_show = models.ForeignKey('Show',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    character = models.ForeignKey(Character, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('actor-detail', args=[str(self.id)])


class Show(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre, help_text='Select a genre for this book')
        language = models.ForeignKey('Language', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
        summary = models.TextField(max_length=1000, help_text='Enter a brief description of the show', null=True)
        cast_of_the_show = models.ManyToManyField(Person,through='Cast')

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('show-detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model for your **ActorDetailView** should be **Person** instead of **Cast**. Then you can use the person record to get all of the casts they belong to.

```
class ActorDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Person
    template_name = 'show/actor-detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ActorDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['casts'] = Cast.objects.filter(person=self.object)
        return context
```

Comment: Thank you for your time @warpri81 . I appreciate it